# Respond to Button Events inside Repeater ItemTemplate

Tags: asp.net, asprepeater

so i have removed the datasouce and just have DataBind() then my page is still blowing and refreshing the page and not in a EDIT mode.

what i am trying to do is when the user click on Edit button then make it inline editing the repeater row.

**END UPDATE**

onItemCommand i have added DataBind()

```
rpt.DataSource = mydatasource; 
rpt.DataBind();
```

after i do that my page is not in edit mode and it blow away and everyting is refreshed 
i have on page_load

```
if (!IsPostBack) 
{
   rpt.DataSource = mydatasource; 
    rpt.DataBind();

}
```

**end update**

I've used repeaters many times without problems but something is going on here. I have a repeater and I'm subscribing to the itemDatabound event, But when i click the button (which is a linkbutton inside my repeater itemtemplate) it does not go to the `ItemDataBound`

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt" runat="server" OnItemCommand="rpt_OnItemCommand" OnItemDataBound="rpt_OnItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
            <asp:Label ID="Label" runat="server" />
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandName="edit" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("MyID") %>'
                Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>' />
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>


    protected void rpt_OnItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
          {
              if (e.CommandName == "delete")
              {
                  //Data.Contacts.RemoveAt(e.Item.ItemIndex);
              }
              else if (e.CommandName == "edit")
              {
                  EditIndex = e.Item.ItemIndex;
              }
              else if (e.CommandName == "save")
              {
                  //          
              }

           }


protected void rpt_OnItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
      {

        if (e.Item.ItemIndex == EditIndex)
        {
          // never come to this line.... after the user click on LinkButton

        }

      }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if this helps but you must call DataBind() in order for for the OnItemDataBound event to fire.  Also my guess is you are trying to set the EditIndex in the OnItemCommand and then use the value in the OnDataBind event.  The events fire in the order OnItemDataBound then OnItemCommand so the EditIndex wouldn't be correct anyway in that situation.

Add rpt.DataBind to the OnItemCommand.  This workded when I tried it from your code, NOTE that you will be binding twice if you aren't using !IsPostBack for original data bind.

```
  rpt.DataSource = strings;

  if (!IsPostBack)
  {
       rpt.DataBind();
  }

 protected void rpt_OnItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
 {
      if (e.CommandName == "delete")
      {
          //Data.Contacts.RemoveAt(e.Item.ItemIndex);
      }
      else if (e.CommandName == "edit")
      {
          EditIndex = e.Item.ItemIndex;
      }
      else if (e.CommandName == "save")
      {
          //          
      }

     rpt.DataBind();

   }
```

Comment: i think you are correct and but when i have the databind() my page refresh and i am out of the edit mode of a repter.. any idea?

Comment: Don't do the rpt.DataSource again.  Just the DataBind();  Set the source still in Page_Load but don't set it again in rpt_OnItemCommand.  Just call the DataBind() method.

Comment: Sorry, this may not work for you but I took the DataSource method out of the !IsPostBack then it hits if I click edit. (Updated Answer)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10024/discussion-between-abu-hamzah-and-tclarkston)

Comment: This article should do exactly what you are trying to do: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/247289/In-place-editing-with-ASP-NET-Repeater

Comment: yes that artcile inspired me and it works great without any issue in my sample project but my real project is giving me a headach

Comment: Sorry, if no one can answer this by tonight and I will try to do it tonight when I get some extra time.

Comment: thanks for your help... it was my silly mistake... i figured out

Answer (score 0):

You must change your rpt_OnItemCommand function.

```
protected void rpt_OnItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "delete")
    {
        //Data.Contacts.RemoveAt(e.Item.ItemIndex);
    }
    else if (e.CommandName == "edit")
    {
        EditIndex = e.Item.ItemIndex;
    }
    else if (e.CommandName == "save")
    {
        //          
    }
    else if (e.CommandName == "Complete")
    {
        // your function goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: How does this fix the problem? It looks like you've just added an extra `else if` condition...

Comment: When you click on a LinkButton inside the repeater it fires the rpt_OnItemCommand function, not rpt_OnItemDataBound. You have written your code inside rpt_OnItemDataBound function but i did it in rpt_OnItemCommand function.

Comment: i wonder why do you want to run your code in OnItemDataBound function. i think it would be much easier in OnItemCommand function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused, but from the example above it looks like you've got it backwards. The button click would *never* fire the `ItemDataBound` event. The `ItemDataBound` event is only called after each item is bound to the repeater.

The button click should fire the `ItemCommand` event however, and if that's not happening I would check to make sure you've actually assigned the `ItemCommand` handler, and also make sure that the command name is valid.

On a side note, this behavior can also happen when the repeater is bound at every postback. Make sure that you're binding the repeater when `!Page.IsPostBack`.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think that the `ItemDataBound` is raised when you click your `LinkButton`? `ItemDataBound` is only fired when `Repeater.DataBind()` is called.
Actually the repeater's `ItemCommand` event is raised instead.