# Every EventVote within table being updated instead of just the one clicked on asp.net c#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Firstly, I am using a repeater to display a number of events. I have an Events table and the columns are "EvtName, EvtType, and EvtVote". I am using a repeater to create each event as shown below

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repeaterEvent" DataSourceID="imgCats">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <div class="jumbotron">   
                                <h2><asp:Label ID="lblEventTest" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("EvtName") %>'></asp:Label></h2>
                                <h3><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("EvtType") %>'></asp:Label></h3>
                                <h4><asp:Label runat="server">Amount Attending: </asp:Label>    
                                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("EvtVote") %>'></asp:Label></h4>
                                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="eventButton" Text="Attending" class="btn btn-primary" OnClick="EventVote_Click"/>
                            </div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
```

The code for event button click is:

```
 public void EventVote_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Events SET EvtVote = EvtVote + 1");
        loadDatabase(cmd);
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
    }
```

and this is updating every single event by 1 instead of just the one clicked on. When the event is being created it is given an ID called eventID so I might need to update my sql query to incorporate that? I'm not too sure how I would do this. Thanks in advance!
On a side-note, I would also like to disable the button for that event clicked once it has been clicked

Si I'm using a repeater item command which is shown below

```
 public void repeaterEvent_ItemCommand(Object Sender, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        // check if the command name is close (if it's the button)
        if (e.CommandName == "Vote")
        {


            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Events SET EvtVote = EvtVote + 1 WHERE EventID = '" + EventID + "'");
            loadDatabase(cmd);
            Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);


        }
    }
```

although it's not updating at all now

Answer (score 0):

Try using the ItemCommand event:

[How to get Row value on button Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312775/how-to-get-row-value-on-button-click)

[ASP.Net Repeater: Get Item, ItemIndex, CommandName and CommandArgument on Click Events](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-Repeater-Get-Item-ItemIndex-CommandName-and-CommandArgument-on-Click-Events.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for this. I've updated my code but it's still not working completely

Comment: Check your syntax in markup and code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10132215/respond-to-button-events-inside-repeater-itemtemplate